# How to install Ubuntu off a USB?

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, usb-creator

I've tried using Startup Disk Creator, but that at first created me an invalid USB that could not boot, and later on was failing to notice the USB entirely.

I tried using unetbootin, but that did not seem to work either, as the normal OS was selected after I've selected BIOS to boot from the USB specifically.

How to install Ubuntu off a USB?

Comment: Which ISO are you putting on the USB, and which OS version are you running Startup Disk Creator (it can be pretty sensitive)?  Have you tried unetbootin or mkusb?

Comment: I was trying to put 15.10 on - neither Startup Disk Creator in 14.04 nor 15.10 worked. In the end, putting 14.04 using a 15.10 Startup Disk Creator  worked.

Answer (score 0):

Using a 14.04 LTS image with Startup Disk Creator in 15.10 worked. Really strange that the massive issues with the Startup Disk Creator aren't being looked at more seriously.